# Finding the most frequent character in a string javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Assuming I have the following string "355385". I need a simple JavaScript that can tell me that the most mentioned character is 5. Thank you in advance.

I tried with this one but no results.

```
var exp = '355385' ;

var exps =exp.split("");

var expCounts = { };

for (var i=0;i<exp.length;i++)

{expCounts["_" + exps[i]] = (expCounts["_" + exps[i]] || 0) + 1 ;

if (expCounts==3) exps=exps[i]; }; exps;
```

Comment: there are only number in the string?

Comment: Recommended solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68963923/9994377

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will loop over every character in the string and keep track of each character's count and the character with the maximum count:

```
var exp = '3553853335' ;
var expCounts = {};
var maxKey = '';
for(var i = 0; i < exp.length; i++)
{
    var key = exp[i];
    if(!expCounts[key]){
     expCounts[key] = 0;
    }
    expCounts[key]++;
    if(maxKey == '' || expCounts[key] > expCounts[maxKey]){
        maxKey = key;
    }
}

console.debug(maxKey + ":" + expCounts[maxKey]);
```

---

**Update:**
Here is an ES6 version that will handle strings where multiple character have the same max count

```js
function maxCount(input) {
    const {max, ...counts} = (input || "").split("").reduce(
    (a, c) => {
        a[c] = a[c] ? a[c] + 1 : 1;
        a.max = a.max < a[c] ? a[c] : a.max;
        return a;
    },
    { max: 0 }
    );

    return Object.entries(counts).filter(([k, v]) => v === max);
}
```

Example (please excuse the crude output):

```
maxCount('--aaaa1111--').join(' | ').replace(/,/g, ':');
```

outputs `1:4 | -:4 | a:4`

Comment: What if I Pass the input as `aabbccdd`??

Comment: Fails for `'--aaaa1111--'`

Comment: @saran3h what do you mean by fails? The log statement only prints out the first character to get the max count, but the variable `expCounts` still tracks all the counts, so multiple values can be retrieved if important `{1: 4, -: 4, a: 4}`

Comment: @saran3h I thought this was interesting, so added an ES6 version which handles this

Comment: fails if string is `""`  Horray for UTF-16 See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60984709/128511)

Answer (score 10):

```
var getMax = function (str) {
 var max = 0,
     maxChar = '';
  str.split('').forEach(function(char){
    if(str.split(char).length > max) {
        max = str.split(char).length;
        maxChar = char;
     }
  });
  return maxChar;
};
```

logs

```
getMax('355385') //5;

getMax('35538533') //3;
```

in equal case it will return first number

```
getMax('3553') //3;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var string  = "355385",
    counter = {};

for (var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    counter[string[i]] = (counter[string[i]] || 0) + 1;
}

var biggest = -1, number;
for (var key in counter) {
    if (counter[key] > biggest) {
        biggest = counter[key];
        number = key;
    }
}

console.log(number);
# 5
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var exp = '355385';
var findMostFrequent = function (string) {
    var chars = {}, first = string.charAt(0);
    chars[first] = 1;
    var maxChar = first, maxCount = 1;

    for (var i = 1; i < string.length; i++) {
        var char = string.charAt(i);
        if (chars[char]) {
            chars[char]++;
        } else {
            chars[char] = 1;
        }
        if (chars[char] > maxCount) {
            maxChar = char;
        }
    }
    return maxChar;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Another Solution

```
function maxChar(str) {

        const charMap = {};
        let max = 0;
        let maxChar = '';

        for(let char of str){
            if(charMap[char]){
                charMap[char]++;
            }else{
                charMap[char] = 1;
            }
        }

        for(let char in charMap){
            if(charMap[char] > max){
                max = charMap[char];
                maxChar = char;
            }
        }

        return maxChar; 
}
```

Result:

```
 maxChar('355385') 
  "5"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get the most frequent character in a string - sort frequency map into an array and then return the first (greatest) value from that array:

```
function highest (string) {
  let array = Array.from(string);
  let frequencyMap = {};
  array.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (!frequencyMap[value]) {
      frequencyMap[value] = 0;
    }
    frequencyMap[value] += 1;
  })
  let frequencyArray = Object.entries(frequencyMap);
  frequencyArray.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[1] < b[1]) {
      return 1;
      }
    if (a[1] > b[1]) {
      return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
  return(frequencyArray[0][0]);
}

console.log(highest("hello World"));
```

> returns "l"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution to find the most frequent character in a string:

```
function getMostRepeatedCharacter(string) {
    return string.split('').reduce((acc,char)=>{
        let len = string.split(char).length - 1;
        return len > acc[1] ? [char,len] : acc
    },['',0])[0]
}

getMostRepeatedCharacter('wediuaududddd') // d
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers above take into consideration that JavaScript internally uses UTF-16

```js
const s = "";

function getMostFrequentChar(s) {
  const len = s.length;
  const freq = {};
  let maxFreq = 0;
  let maxChar;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    const isPair = (s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xF800) == 0xD800;
    const c = isPair ? s.substr(i++, 2) : s[i];
    const f = (freq[c] || 0) + 1;
    freq[c] = f;
    if (f > maxFreq) {
      maxFreq = f;
      maxChar = c;
    }
  }
  return {maxFreq, maxChar, freq}
}

console.log(getMostFrequentChar(s));
```

Note: the code above assumes the string is valid UTF-16. It's possible to construct a string that is not valid UTF-16 in which case maybe you could change `isPair` to

```
const isPair = len - i > 1 &&
               s.charCodeAt(i    ) & 0xF800) == 0xD800 &&
               s.charCodeAt(i + 1) & 0xF800) == 0xD800;
```

But it's not clear what a character with an invalid UTF-16 value means.

It also won't handle more funky unicode

```
s = ""
```

[There are many graphmemes that take multiple unicode code points](http://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html)

Also, splitting the string using `split` is SSSSSSLLLLLOOOOWWWW and a huge memory hog if the string is long.

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another answer to this question:

For this I have considered that the character can be of whatevert kind except a space

```
function findHighestFreqInString(str) {
    if (!str) return null
    let cleanedStr = str.replace(/\s/g, '') //assumes no spaces needed
    if (cleanedStr.length === 0) return null
    let strObj = {}
    let topChar = ''
    for (let val of cleanedStr) {
        strObj[val] = (strObj[val] || 0) + 1
        if (topChar === '' || strObj[val] >= strObj[topChar]) topChar = val
    }
    return topChar
}
```

Here is how you would use it:

```
findHighestFreqInString('my name is Someone') // returns: e
findHighestFreqInString('') // returns: Null
findHighestFreqInString('    ') // returns: Null
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is:

```
let str = '355385';
function mostFrequentCharacter(str) {
        let charactersArr = str.split(''),
            bins = {};

        charactersArr.map(el => bins[el] = (bins[el] || 0) + 1); 
    return Object.keys(bins).map(key => ({
            name: key,
          count: bins[key]
    })).sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count)[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Want to share this ES6 functional approach. Please provide your input.

```
function maxChar(myStr) {
  let charObj = {};
  return [...myStr].reduce((_, char) => {
    if (char in charObj) charObj[char]++;
    else if (char !== " ") charObj[char] = 1;
    return Object.keys(charObj).reduce((a, b) => {
      return charObj[a] > charObj[b] ? a : b;
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach will be like this:

```
function maxChar(str) {
  const charMap = {};
  let max = 0;
  let maxChar = '';
```

start by making an object of words and how many they repeated, to do that we have to loop through the string using `for` `of` and implementing the conditions:

```
  for (let char of str) {
    if (charMap[char]) {
      charMap[char]++;
    } else {
      charMap[char] = 1;
    }
  }
```

and now loop through the object using `for` `in`

```
  for (let char in charMap) {
    if (charMap[char] > max) {
      max = charMap[char];
      maxChar = char;
    }
  }

  return maxChar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is another (bizarre) way 
It substitute the current character with blank for check how many times is present in the string making the difference of length with original pattern

```
var str = "355385";
var mostLength = 0;
var characterMostLength;
for(t = 0; t< 10; t++)
{
    var res = str.length - str.replace(new RegExp(t, "g"), "").length;
    if (res > mostLength){
        characterMostLength = t;
        mostLength = res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming there's likely to be more other characters than the one you're searching for, it's probably more memory efficient to replace all characters EXCEPT the one you're looking for with a blank and then just check the length of the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(N) {
    var textToArr = N.split('');
    var newObj = {};
    var newArr = [];

    textToArr.map((letter) => {
        if(letter in newObj){
            newObj[letter] = newObj[letter]+1;
        } else {
            if(letter !== ' '){
               newObj = Object.assign(newObj, {[letter]: 1})
            }
        }
    });

    for(let i in newObj){
        newArr.push({name: i, value: newObj[i]})
    }

    var res = newArr.sort((a,b) => b.value-a.value)[0];
    return res.name+':'+res.value
}

solution("hello world");
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple Idea that only includes one pass-through with a hashmap. The only thing this does not do is handle several max numbers. I really hope you enjoy my solution :) .

```
function maxChar(str) {
    //Create the output and the hashmap
    let m = {}, ans

    //Loop through the str for each character
    //Use reduce array helper because of the accumulator

    str.split('').reduce((a, c) => {

        //Increments Map at location c(character) unless it does not already exist

        m[c] = m[c] + 1|| 1

        //This checks to see if the current passthrough of m[c] is greater than or equal to the accumulator, if it is, set the answer equal to the current character. If it's not keep the ans the same.

        ans = m[c] >= a ? c : ans

        //Only increment the accumulator if Map at location c(character) is greater than the accumulator. Make sure to return it otherwise it won't increment.

        return a = m[c] > a ? a + 1 : a
    }, 1)

    //Lastly return the answer
    return ans
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to find maximum number of occurring character in string

```
var arr = "5255522322";
    var freq:any = {};
    var num;
    for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
      num = arr[i];
    freq[num] = freq[num] >= 1 ? freq[num] + 1 : 1;
    }
    var sortable:any = [];
    for(let i in freq)
    {
      sortable.push(i);   
    }
    var max = freq[sortable[0]];
     var data:any = "";
   var value = sortable[0];
    for(let i=0;i<sortable.length;i++) {

      if(max > freq[sortable[i]]){
        data = "key" + value + " " + "value" + max;
      }else{
        value = sortable[i]
        max = freq[sortable[i]];
      }
    }

    console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function maxChara(string) {
  charMap = {};
  maxNum = 0;
  maxChar = "";

  string.toString().split("").forEach(item => {
    if (charMap[item]) {
      charMap[item]++;
    } else {
      charMap[item] = 1;
    }
  });

  for (let char in charMap) {
    if (charMap[char] > maxNum) {
      maxNum = charMap[char];
      maxChar = char;
    }
  }
  return maxChar;
}

let result = maxChara(355385);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here **str** will the string that needs to be verified.

```
function maxCharacter(str){

let str1 = str; let reptCharsCount=0; let ele='';let maxCount=0;
let charArr = str1.split('');
for(let i=0; i< str1.length; i++){
    reptCharsCount=0;
    for(let j=0; j< str1.length; j++){
        if(str1[i] === str1[j]) {
            reptCharsCount++;
        }
    }

    if(reptCharsCount > maxCount) {
        ele = str1[i];
        maxCount = reptCharsCount; 
    }
}
return ele;
```

}

**input**

maxCharacter('asdefdfdsdfseddssdfsdnknmwlqweeeeeeeesssssssssssseeee');

**output**

"s"

Answer (score 0):

```
function freq(str) {
        var freqObj = {};
        str.forEach((item) => {
            if (freqObj[item]) {
                freqObj[item]++;
            }
            else {
                freqObj[item] = 1;
            }

        });
        return freqObj;


    }
    function findmaxstr(str) {
        let max = 0,res,freqObj;
        freqObj = freq(str.split(""));
        for(let keys in freqObj){
            if (freqObj[keys] > max) {
                max = freqObj[keys];
                res = keys;
            }
        }
        console.log(res);
        return res;
    }



findmaxstr("javasdasdsssssscript");
```

Comment: Could you point out in your answer in what it answers the quesion?

Comment: Why do you think this is simpler or more performant than the other provided answers?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const maxChar = (str) => {
  let obj = {};
  for (let char of str) {
    (!obj[char]) ? obj[char] = 1: obj[char]++;
  }
  maxCharcount = Math.max(...Object.values(obj));
  const key = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] === maxCharcount);
  console.log(`Most repeated character/characters in the given string "${str}" is/are given below which repeated ${maxCharcount} times`);
  console.log(...key);
}

maxChar("355385");
```

Comment: Code-only answers, while they may solve the problem, are rarely good answers. Consider adding an explanation of what your code does and in this case, because there are alot of existing answers already, point out what makes your additional answer worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, where it also checks for lower and upperCase characters with the same max count and returns a Lower ASCII character as a Max.

```js
function mostFrequent(text) {
    let charObj={}
    
    for(let char of text){
        if(char!==' '){
            if(charObj.hasOwnProperty(char)) charObj[char]=charObj[char]+1;
                else charObj[char]= 1
        }
    } 
    
    let maxOccurance= Object.keys(charObj)[0], i=0;
    
    for(let property in charObj){
        if(i>0){
            if(charObj[property]> charObj[maxOccurance]) 
                maxOccurance= property
            else if(charObj[property]=== charObj[maxOccurance]) 
            {
                if(property<maxOccurance) 
                    maxOccurance=property 
                }
            } 
            i++
    }
    
    return [maxOccurance, charObj[maxOccurance]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = '355385';
let max = 0;
let char = '';
str.split('').forEach((item) => {
  let current = str.split(item).length;
  if (current > max) {
    max = current;
    char = item;
  }
});

console.log(char + ' occurred ' + (max - 1) + ' times');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var exp = '35585' ;
var expCounts = { };
let maxChar = ''
let count = 0

for(let i = 0; i < exp.length; i++){
let char = exp[i]

expCounts[char] = expCounts[char] + 1 || 1

if(expCounts[char] > count){
   maxChar = char
   count = expCounts[char]
   
}
console.log(maxChar)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkNoofOccurenance(string) {
  const arr = [...new Set(string.split(''))].sort();
  const finalObj = {};
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    finalObj[item] = string.split(item).length - 1;
  });
  const item=Object.keys(finalObj).reduce((occ, toBeComapir)=>finalObj[occ]>finalObj[toBeComapir]?occ:toBeComapir)
  return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Hasmaps we can find the most frequent char and occurrence all in O(N) time complexity. Below is the code. I have used one hasmap to save all the values and while i am doing it, i am also calculating the max occurrence and the max char.

```js
var mostFreq = function(s) {
    let myMap = new Map();
    let temp;
    let counter = 0;
    let mostFrequentChar;
    for(let i =0;i <s.length;i++){
       if(myMap.has(s.charAt(i))){
           temp = myMap.get(s.charAt(i));
           temp = temp + 1;
           myMap.delete(s.charAt(i));
           myMap.set(s.charAt(i) , temp)
           if(temp > counter){
               counter = temp;
               mostFrequentChar = s.charAt(i);
           }
       }else{
           myMap.set(s.charAt(i), 1)
       }    
    }
    
    //if you want number of occerance of most frequent char  = counter
    //if you want list of each individual char and its occurrence = myMap
    //if you just want the char that is most frequence = mostFrequentChar;
    
    return mostFrequentChar;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count of the letter as well, You can do this

```js
  const { letter, count } = input.split("").reduce(
    (acc, letter) => {
      const count = input.split(letter).length - 1;
      return count > acc.count
        ? { letter, count }
        : { letter: acc.letter, count: acc.count };
    },
    { letter: "", count: 0 }
  );
```

Here We are splitting the string, applying a reduce to the result. The Reduce Counts how many instances of a character are there in a string, using `input.split(letter).length - 1;` And if the count is greater than the previous count, updates the accumulated value to be the current value

Answer (score 0):

```js
let string = "355385";

function printFirstRepeat(str){
    let output= {};
    for (let char of str) {
        char = char.toLowerCase();
        output[char] = ++output[char] || 1;
        if(output[char] > 1) return char;
    }

    return "Not Found"
}

console.log(printFirstRepeat(string));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm: Find maximum occurring character in a string** (time complex: O(N))

I'll provide my solution to this algo-problem by utilizing the most recent concepts of javascript

```
const getMaxCharacter = (str) => {
  let max = 0;
  let maxChar = '';
  str.split('').forEach((char) => {
    if (str.split(char).length > max) {
      max = str.split(char).length - 1;
      maxChar = char;
    }
  });
  return `The max letter is : ${maxChar} and the max number of times it is seen is: ${max} times`;
};
```

Let's express an easy way of testing the function logic I wrote it:

```
const letter = 'Hello Student';    
getMaxCharacter(letter);
```

In the function developed, I've used the concepts below:

- Arrow Function
- Anonymous Funciton
- Declare property by using let/const
- Template Literals
- forEach(); (array helper) & split()

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and optimized solution and it returns the first occurring char if there are chars equals in counts

```js
function maxOccurance(str) {
  let maxOccurringChar = "";
  const charMap = {};
  for (let index = 0; index < str.length; index++) {
    const ele = str.charAt(index);

    if (!charMap[ele]) {
      charMap[ele] = {
        startIndex: index,
        value: 1
      };
    } else {
      charMap[ele].value = charMap[ele].value + 1;
    }

    if (
      !maxOccurringChar ||
      charMap[maxOccurringChar].value < charMap[ele].value
    ) {
      maxOccurringChar = ele;
    } else if (
      charMap[maxOccurringChar].value === charMap[ele].value &&
      charMap[ele].startIndex < charMap[maxOccurringChar].startIndex
    ) {
      maxOccurringChar = ele;
    }
  }

  return maxOccurringChar;
}

console.log(  maxOccurance("bacdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
);
```

Comment: To improve your answer, you could add a description of what your code does, and particularly in what way it is optimized

Answer (score 0):

You can use array de-structure to loop it through and take the first or all of them in one round or `o(1)`

```js
function findMostRepeatedChar(str, returnAll = false) {
  const list = {};
  let mostRepeated = { char: "", count: 0 };
  const characters = [...str];

  characters.forEach((char) => {
    list[char] = list[char] ? list[char] + 1 : 1;

    if (list[char] > mostRepeated.count)
      mostRepeated = { char, count: list[char] };
    else if (list[char] === mostRepeated.count && returnAll)
      mostRepeated = {
        char: `${mostRepeated.char},${char}`,
        count: list[char],
      };
  });

  return mostRepeated;
}

console.log(findMostRepeatedChar("355385"))
console.log(findMostRepeatedChar("Hello wolrd!"))
console.log(findMostRepeatedChar("aabb"));
console.log(findMostRepeatedChar("aabb",true));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p id = "myString">Hello World! I am Julio!</p>

    <p id = "mRCharacter"></p>

    <script>
        var string = document.getElementById("myString").innerHTML;

        var mRCharater = mostRepetedCharacter(string);
        document.getElementById("mRCharacter").innerHTML = mRCharater;
        console.log(mRCharater);

        function mostRepetedCharacter(string){
            var mRCharater = "";
            var strLength = string.length;
            var i = 0;
            var count = 0;
            var max = 0;
            var rest = strLength - 1;
            while (i < strLength){
                var j = i + 1;
                while (j <= rest){
                    if (string[i] === string[j]){
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (count > max){
                        max = count;
                        mRCharater = string[i];
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
                count = 0;
            }
            return mRCharater;
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>

    enter code here
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by providing an explanation and improving the formatting and skipping unnecessary bits of code.