# Whats wrong with my javascript code to return most common letter?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a solution that will return the most common letter in a string, and the number of times that letter appears.
The solution I came up was to loop through the string, holding one letter at a time in a variable called letter, and comparing all other letters to this. Then once the string ended, the loop would hold the second letter and repeat.

The problem I am getting is it just returns the first letter in the string ever time. It gets the number of matches correct, but it ignores the fact that other letters have more matches.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var match = 0;
var matchCount = 0;
var letter = 0;
var count = 0;
indx1 = 0;
indx2 = 0;

function problemTen(a) {
  while (indx1 < a.length) {
    letter = a[indx1]; //hold the first letter in the string in the letter variable

    while (indx2 < a.length) { //now rotate through every other letter to compare
      if (a[indx2] == letter) { //compare 
        count += 1; // if there is a match, add one to the count variable to hold the number of matches
      }
      indx2 += 1; //cycle through the rest of the string  
    }
    if (matchCount === 0 || count > matchCount) { // if it’s the first time around,     or if this letter had more matches than the previous letter
      match = letter; // hold the letter in the match variable
      matchCount = count; //hold the number of matches in the count     variable
    }
    indx1 += 1; //cycle through the first variable that you compare
  }
  return [match, matchCount]; //return results
}

console.log(problemTen("astrings"));
```

edit: here is the solution I came up with.

```
function problemTen (a) {
  var match = 0;
  var matchCount = 0;
  var letter;

  for(var indx1 = 0; indx1<a.length; indx1++) {
    letter = a[indx1];              
    var count = 1;                  

    for(var indx2 = indx1 + 1; indx2<a.length; indx2++) {         
      if(a[indx2] == letter) {        
        count +=1;                 
      }
    }
    if(matchCount === 0 || count>matchCount) { 
      match = letter;                  
      matchCount =count;               
    }   
  }
  return [match, matchCount];       
}

console.log(problemTen("iamatinystring"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the most frequent character in a string javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590023/finding-the-most-frequent-character-in-a-string-javascript)

Comment: Do you ever set `indx2` back to `0`?

Comment: Unrelated side note: why are all your variables global?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe check this solution, it's time complexity is linear compared to the one you're trying to achieve, which is quadraple:

```
function problemTen(a) {
  var array = a.split('');
  var max = 0;
  var letter;

  var counter = array.reduce(function(memo, item) {
    memo[item] = memo[item] ? memo[item] + 1 : 1;
    if (memo[item] > max) {
      max = memo[item];
      letter = item;
    }
    return memo;
  }, {});

  return [letter, max];
}

console.log(problemTen("astrings"));
```

If you want to stick to your solution though, the problem is, when you run the outer while loop again, you're not resetting the indx2 and count variables, so, indx2 = a.length already, and the inner while loop doesn't run anymore to count letters. with adding these resets, your code should be something like this:

```
function problemTen(a) {
  var match = 0;
  var matchCount = 0
  var letter = 0;
  var count = 0;
  indx1 = 0;
  indx2 = 0;

  while (indx1 < a.length) {
    letter = a[indx1]; //hold the first letter in the string in the letter variable

    while (indx2 < a.length) { //now rotate through every other letter to compare
      if (a[indx2] === letter) { //compare 
        count += 1; // if there is a match, add one to the count variable to hold the number of matches
      }
      indx2 += 1; //cycle through the rest of the string  
    }
    if (matchCount === 0 || count > matchCount) { // if it’s the first time around,     or if this letter had more matches than the previous letter
      match = letter; // hold the letter in the match variable
      matchCount = count; //hold the number of matches in the count     variable
    }
    indx1 += 1; //cycle through the first variable that you compare

    // HERE WE RESET indx2 and match to 0
    indx2 = 0;
    match = 0;

  }
  return [match, matchCount]; //return results
}

console.log(problemTen("astrings"));
```

In fact, to achieve O(n) time complexity, you don't necessarily use reduce, you can do it just using one loop as well, and it will surely be much faster, I just prefer functional programming as it results better readibility:

```
function problemTen(a) {
  var max = 0;
  var letter;
  var counter = {};

  for (var i = 0, l = a.length; i<l; i++) {
    counter[a[i]] = counter[a[i]] ? counter[a[i]] + 1 : 1;
    if (counter[a[i]] > max) {
      max = counter[a[i]];
      letter = a[i];
    }
  }

  return [letter, max];
}

console.log(problemTen("astrings"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I wound up switching over to using for loops and realized that count and indx2 weren't being reset.  I posted the solution I came up with above.

Comment: There is nothing wrong using while loop, in fact it's generally more readable compared to for loop, but you can easily make mistake like forgetting increasing/decreasing the index you follow.

Comment: ok. I will keep that in mind. I tend to find for loops easier to keep track of, which is exactly why I use them. But I should practice while loops more. Thanks again!

Comment: Shouldn't your memoized version be setting `max` to `counter[key]` when it finds a new max?

Comment: well said @MikeC. I just wrote it quickly, without thinking much really, basically second loop is not necessary. I just corrected my solution.

Comment: Just want to add a reference to MDN [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) which also includes a pollyfill for older browsers.  Nice answer Ahmet Cetin

Comment: @J.Mead: can you accept my solution if it works for you? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You task is to find the (first) character with the highest number of occurences in a given string. If you do not want to use extra memory like in Ahmet Cetin's answer you really need two loops here. You also need on point for the current character and its number of occurences and one for the actaul top postion and its number of occurances, four variables.

This is a place where a `for` loop would be better suited than your `while`-loops but both would work.

```
var teststring = "teststring";

function problemTen(s){
  var count = 0;      // counter for current character
  var last = 0;       // counter for actual highest character
  var character = ""; // current character
  var top = "";       // highest character

  for(var i = 0;i < s.length;i++){     // Loop over the full string
    character = s[i];                  // set current character
    for(var j = 0;j < s.length; j++){  // Loop over the full string
      if(s[j] === character){          // we found another occurence
        count++;                       // increment the counter
      }
    }
    if(last < count){   // the actual char. has more occ. than the last one
      last = count;     // set the top counter to the current counter
      top = character;  // set the top character to the current character
    }
    count = 0;        // reset the current counter
  }
  return [top,last];    // return the character and count of the to one
}

problemTen(teststring);
```

Comment: well, considering the memory power of the current computers, i prefer speed over memory usage, and in fact memory will be released for garbage collection as soon as you finish running it. generally speaking loop inside loop is no-no unless you really need it.

Comment: @AhmetCetin Your code does the same, it loops twice (`reduce` is a full loop). You can do without by using a separate array with a maximum length: the length of the alphabet or the length of the string if the string is shorter. Twice that because it needs to be a key-value array. But it would be O(n log n) at the end not O(n^2) as with the two loops.

Comment: Well, not really, my code is looping twice indeed, but not inside of each other, so it's 2n, as multiplier is not counted, my solution is O(n). And the above solution, in fact, is O(n^2), both outer and inner loops are running till the end without any break or return statement.

Comment: You can achieve O(n log n), if you exit the inner loop when you find what you're looking for, like in sort algorithms, but it's not the case here.

Comment: @AhmetCetin What makes you think that something like `arra[item]` with `item` a key does run in O(1)? Even if the interpreter keeps it sorted it is at best O(log n) (but it could be a hash-list, didn't check), so what you are doing is at worst O(n log n) (worst case is if if both the string and the alphabet are the same and unordered)

Comment: @Pevara Yes, that's expected, I even thought it would be more, so what does the new FF in a Linux 64 Bit? The for-loop is *faster* by 41 procent? That's really surprising! Does Firefox implement `reduce` that badly?

Comment: @Pevara, I just added one more solution in my answer, which uses one for loop and using object for the counter, so you need one loop in fact. Here is the test result: http://jsperf.com/most-occuring-letter/5

Comment: The for-loop is still the fastest in Firefox but with Ahmet Cetin's change I think it is the search in an `Object` that is badly implemented, or at least not as optimized as in Chrome. Well, good to now. Thanks!

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: if we're talking about my reduce solution:array=a.split('') is O(n), array.reduce loop is also O(n), memo is object (hash table) and no loop on it anyway, therefore whole operation is O(n).

Comment: You've gotta love a good discussion! Added my Safari, Opera and (old) FF to the tests, and it seems to be a FF thing indeed. Yet another argument to convince my FF using colleagues to switch to Chrome ;) Good night!

Comment: If we're talking about the solution above with nested for loops, both inner and outer loops are running fully so O(n^2) in time complexity. When you talk about Big-O, you don't consider the optimization of compilers. It's only about operations you perform depending on the size of dataset. You can say best case, worst case scenarios but as the above solution runs both loops fully nested, it's simply O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

As is, the code loops through the string only once. For that you should reset indx2 to 0 before the inner while loop.
Done that then you will have to also reset the 'count' variable at every inner loop.

An optimization is to have indx2 start from indx1+1, and have count=1 at the beginning of the inner loop.

```js
var match = 0;
var matchCount = 0;
var letter = 0;
var count = 0;
indx1 = 0;
indx2 = 0;

function problemTen(a) {
  while (indx1 < a.length) {
    letter = a[indx1]; //hold the first letter in the string in the letter variable
    indx2 = 0; // <---- [sal] reset the inner loop starting point
    count = 0; // <---- [sal] reset the inner loop counter
    while (indx2 < a.length) { //now rotate through every other letter to compare
      if (a[indx2] == letter) { //compare 
        count += 1; // if there is a match, add one to the count variable to hold the number of matches
      }
      console.log(letter, a[indx2], count);
      indx2 += 1; //cycle through the rest of the string  
    }
    if (matchCount === 0 || count > matchCount) { // if it’s the first time around,     or if this letter had more matches than the previous letter
      match = letter; // hold the letter in the match variable
      matchCount = count; //hold the number of matches in the count     variable
    }
    indx1 += 1; //cycle through the first variable that you compare
  }
  return [match, matchCount]; //return results
}

console.log(problemTen("astrings"));
```

Comment: @J.Mead: can you revise your -1 on my answer? You correctly flagged it, as it wasn't fully working, but I edited it since, and the result has been correct for a while now.