# How to get longest sequences of equal characters and how many are they if more than one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sequence, equals

Examples:

- 11ADD = 2 equal, 2 sequences
- 115222 3 equals, 1 sequence
- ABCDEF10 = 1 equal, 8 sequences

Result should contain

1. Length of the maximum sequentially repeated character count.
2. Number of repeated character sequences that match that maximum length count

Here is what I'm trying, converting dec to Hex, then find equal seq. and how many are they

```js
let n = [1, 26, 221];
let arr = [];
let hex = '';
let maxSequence = 0;
let currentCounter = 0;
let sequences = 0;


arr.forEach(element => {
  hex += element.toString(16).toLocaleUpperCase();
});
let newarr = [];
const hexSplit = [...hex];

hexSplit.forEach((element, x) => {
  if (hexSplit[x + 1] === hexSplit[x]) {
    currentCounter++;
    newarr.push(hexSplit[x])
  }
  if (currentCounter > maxSequence) {
    maxSequence = currentCounter;
    sequences += 1;

  } else if (maxSequence === 0) {
    maxSequence = 1;
    sequences = hexSplit.length;
  }
});

console.log(maxSequence, sequences)
```

Comment: the sequences are going to be composed by a single `char` or they could be `string`? `ABCABC1` in this string the sequence `ABC` is repeated twice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the most frequent character in a string javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590023/finding-the-most-frequent-character-in-a-string-javascript)

Comment: @liam I don't see that as a duplicate as two values are desired here (how many, and the count of the maximum length sequences) and it is not "occurrence" but sequential occurrence that is desired here.

Comment: What is the expected result of `ABCDEA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALL the credit here goes to the OTHER answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52152057/125981  I merely adapted it to return results against an array of values.  Please up-vote/accept that one perhaps.

```js
var sequences = ['11ADD', '115222', 'ABCDEF10'];

function getLongestSeqList(input) {
  return input
    .match(/(.)\1*/g)
    .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
    .filter((a, i, arr) => a.length === arr[0].length)
}

function getValues(s) {
  let seq = getLongestSeqList(s);
  return {
    Count: seq.length,
    Len: seq[0].length
  };
}
sequences.forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(getValues(s));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of the longest sequences of equal characters with a simple regex, sorting it by length in descending order and filtering by the length of first (which is the longest):

```js
function getLongestSeqList(input) {
  return input
          .match(/(.)\1*/g)
          .sort((a,b) => b.length - a.length)
          .filter((a,i,arr) => a.length === arr[0].length)
}

console.log(getLongestSeqList('11ADD')); // ["11", "DD"]
console.log(getLongestSeqList('115222')); // ["222"]
console.log(getLongestSeqList('ABCDEF10')); // ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "1", "0"]
```

Comment: Add in effect for each example `console.log("Count",getLongestSeqList('115222').length,"Len",getLongestSeqList('115222')[0].length);` and I can buy off on this one as an answer that might be optomized  i.e. make that function return those results in effect.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const getLongest = seq => seq.reduce(({
  longest,
  currentItem,
  currentLength,
  items
}, item) => {

  const newCurrentLength = currentItem === item ? currentLength + 1 : 1;
  if (newCurrentLength > longest) {
    // we have a new longest sequence, assign new values
    // to longest and items
    return {
      currentItem: item,
      currentLength: newCurrentLength,
      longest: newCurrentLength, 
      items: 1,
    };
  } else if (newCurrentLength === longest) {
    // we match the previously longest,
    // add the item to the sequence list
    return {
      currentItem: item,
      currentLength: longest,
      longest, 
      items: items + 1,
    };
  } else {
    // this is still a shorter sequence,
    // just update the local state
    return {
      currentItem: item,
      currentLength: newCurrentLength,
      longest,
      items
    }
  }


  return ;

}, {
  longest: 0,
  currentItem: undefined,
  currentLength: 0,
  items: 0
});

const values = ["11ADD", "115222", "ABCDEF10"];

const res = values.map(s => s.split("")).map(getLongest);

console.log(res);
```

Note that with this organisation you can easily add data to your result, such as what value was the longest sequence, where it started etc...

Comment: For the first example, you have `"currentItem": "D",`but ignore the "11" in that string - perhaps `currentItem` is better as an array? (but that does not mean the question is unanswered here.

Comment: currentItem in the result is the last item actually  which is Din the first example

Comment: To read the results: `items` is the number of different values for which there was the longer sequence. `longest` is the length of that sequence. The other are just local state. Of course you could replace `items` by an array and do `items : [...items, item]`  in the second `if` clause` to have the values (and the order in which they appeared).