# How do I return only the letter that repeats the most times?

Tags: javascript

How do I return only the letter that repeats the most times? How to make it return only the result e = 5 in the following case

```
enter code here
var s = "Teeeeessttt"
var x = (s.toLowerCase());
function count() {
array_elements = ([...x]);;
array_elements.sort();

var current = null;
var cnt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array_elements.length; i++) {
    if (array_elements[i] != current) {
        if (cnt > 0) {
            document.write(current + ' - ' + cnt + '<br>');
        }
        current = array_elements[i];
        cnt = 1;
    } else {
        cnt++;
    }
}
if (cnt > 0) {
    document.write(current + ' - ' + cnt);
}
}

count();
```

Comment: This would return `['e', 5]`,   `[...[...s].reduce((a,v)=>a.set(v,a.get(v)+1||1),new Map())].sort((a,b)=>b[1]-a[1])[0]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the most frequent character in a string javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590023/finding-the-most-frequent-character-in-a-string-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would need to count the amount of times a character occurs. You could use the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to loop over each character and store that character as a key in an object. The value of the key should represent the amount of times the character has occurred.

It would look like the object below.

```
{
  "t": 4,
  "e": 5,
  "s": 2
}
```

From here you want to look for the highest number and return the key that corresponds to it. I've borrowed the solution of [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376295/getting-key-with-the-highest-value-from-object) to get the highest count of the object using another `reduce` loop.

```js
const string = "Teeeeessttt";

const mostOccuringCharacter = string => {
  // Count the occurence of each character.
  const count = [...string.toLowerCase()].reduce((counter, char) => {
    counter[char] = (counter[char] || 0) + 1;
    return counter;
  }, {});
    
  // Compare the values with each other and return the
  // character with the highest count.
  const highestChar = Object.keys(count).reduce((a, b) => 
    count[a] > count[b] ? a : b);
    
  // Return an array with the character and the count.
  return [highestChar, count[highestChar]]
};

const [ char, count ] = mostOccuringCharacter(string);

console.log(`${char} = ${count}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

@UKS points out a dupe for this, interestingly there was a post with issues with funcky unicode.. eg.  , but no solution was shown for this.

So with that in mind I thought I would knock up a version that handles unicode nicely.  I've also split into multiple functions for re-use.  As you can see it's also easy to alter to find the least used character if so wanted.  Not sure if this will handle 100% unicode, there might be some even more funcky ones. :)

```js
function unicodeStrSplit(str) {
  const x = [...str];
  //let handle some funcky unicode
  for (let p=x.length-1;p>0;p--)
    if(x[p].charCodeAt(0)===0xd83c){x[p-1] += x[p], x.splice(p, 1) };
  return x;
}

function arrayCounter(arr) {
  return [...arr.reduce((a,v)=>a.set(v,a.get(v)+1||1),new Map())].
    sort((a,b) => b[1]-a[1]);
}

function stringCounter(str) {
  return arrayCounter(unicodeStrSplit(str));
}


console.log(stringCounter("Teeeeessttt").shift()); //first array item
//funcky unicode too.
console.log(stringCounter('').shift()); //first array item
//also let's get the least used
console.log(stringCounter('').pop()); //last array item
```